# Coefficients in a pair of formal power series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

Let's suppose I have formal power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}a_k \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\binom{k}{j} X^j=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n X^n$. I would like a clean way to write the formal sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n$ in terms of $\{a_k\}$.

Comment: Do note that the left-hand side will not in general make sense as a power series.  For example, if $a_k = (-1)^{k+1}$, then the power on $X^j$ is $(-1)^j \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{k}{j} \approx (-1)^j \frac1{j!} \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^j$, which diverges.  Are you sure that the equation you wrote is the one you meant?

Comment: @Theo, Perhaps OP is only interested in cases where the left side makes sense as a power series.

Comment: @Gerry, That seems like a reasonable interpretation.  In any case, I had misread the problem as to ask for each $C_n$ in terms of the $a_k$, which would be given by an infinite-dimensional inverse matrix except that the matrix in question is not invertible, rather than just wanting their sum.

Answer (score 0):

If we put $X=1$ in the equation $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}a_k \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\binom{k}{j} X^j=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n X^n$$

Then we find $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k=0$$ becasue in the LHS $$\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\binom{k}{j} =0$$

This seems to be the answer. Please point out if I am missing something.

Comment: I like this idea. I didn't think of it. The values of $X$ that I would ultimately need to take however are $0<X<1$.

Comment: Actually the value of $X$ doesn't matter here because it is a formal power series. But if you compute $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$ after finding out $C_n$ explicitly from the identity then it is the same as putting $X=1$ in the identity.